# JDialog doesn't position correctly on right monitor on Windows 10 with scaling at 150%

Tags: java, swing, dialog, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors (Windows 10). Left monitor (not 4K) is set to 100% scaling. Right monitor (4K) is set to 150% scaling.
When I run a Java Swing application (OpenJDK 11) (code provided) on the right monitor, the JOptionPane popup doesn't appear in the correct place (centered above the JFrame). 
My questions are : Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else encountered this? ... and do they have a solution?

Windows 10
Two Monitors: Left with no scaling, Right with 150% scaling
OpenJDK 11.0.1
Java Swing application

```
public static final void main(String...strings) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        sb.append("YOU NEED AT LEAST TWO SCREENS TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE.").append('\n');
        sb.append('\n');
        sb.append("IN WINDOWS DISPLAY SETTINGS :\n");
        sb.append("   1) SET LEFT SCREEN TO 100% scale\n");
        sb.append("   2) SET RIGHT SCREEN TO 150% scale\n");
        sb.append('\n');
        sb.append("Verifying your environment...\n");
        sb.append('\n');

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gdarray = ge.getScreenDevices();
        sb.append("Number of screens detected: ").append(gdarray.length).append('\n');

        for ( int i=0; i<gdarray.length; ++i ) {
            sb.append('\n');
            sb.append("Screen #").append(i+1).append(":\n");
            GraphicsDevice gd = gdarray[i];
            if ( gd instanceof Win32GraphicsDevice ) {
                Win32GraphicsDevice wgd = (Win32GraphicsDevice)gd;
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = wgd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle r = gc.getBounds();
                sb.append("    x = ").append(r.x).append("\n");
                sb.append("    y = ").append(r.y).append("\n");
                sb.append("    width = ").append(r.width).append("\n");
                sb.append("    height = ").append(r.height).append("\n");
                sb.append("    scaleX = ").append(wgd.getDefaultScaleX()).append("\n");
                sb.append("    scaleY = ").append(wgd.getDefaultScaleY()).append("\n");
            }
            else {
                sb.append("   Not Windows ?\n");
            }
        }

        sb.append('\n');
        sb.append("Move application to screen 1 and click button below. Popup appears centered over application.\n");
        sb.append('\n');
        sb.append("Move application to screen 2 and click button below. Popup does not appear centered over application.\n");
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        sb.append("An error occurred while trying to verify your environment,\nbut you may still be able to demonstrate the bug");
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setText(sb.toString());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);

    JButton showPopup = new JButton("Show Popup");
    showPopup.addActionListener((e) -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "This should appear directly over main frame.");
    });

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(showPopup);
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,0,0,0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 650);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

JOptionPane popup should be centered over JFrame. It works on the left monitor with no scaling. It doesn't work on the right monitor.